# VBA: Copying cells from one workbook to another yields blank results

Tags: vba, excel

I have four subroutines that each take a specified external file and copy a sheet from that file into a sheet in the workbook the sub is running from.  For 3/4 subs, this works great.  The fourth sub, however, is giving me blank results in the destination.  The code is the same across all four subs, just with the filenames changed.  The biggest difference I see that could be causing this error is that the source workbook in question is protected.  I am unlocking it using my sub and then copying the files.  Adding a watch to the source shows the entire range as "Variant/Empty"

```
' declare variables
    Dim financialReportBook As Workbook
    Set financialReportBook = Workbooks.Open(FileNavPrompt.financialFilePath)
    Dim financialSheet As Worksheet
    Set financialSheet = FileNavPrompt.mainBook.Sheets("Financial Status")
    Dim copyRange As String
    copyRange = "A1:AA5000"

' unprotect workbook
    financialReportBook.Unprotect ("{password removed}")          ' unprotect workbook for copying

' pull data from report
    financialSheet.Cells.Clear      ' start with a clean slate
    financialSheet.Range(copyRange).Value = financialReportBook.Sheets(1).Range(copyRange).Value
    financialSheet.Range(copyRange).NumberFormat = financialReportBook.Sheets(1).Range(copyRange).NumberFormat                                

' close report
    financialReportBook.Close False

' unrelated code continues below...
```

Comment: Q1: Why use 4 separate subs when you can do it all within a simple Loop?  Q2: You have not provided a minimum amount of code in order to diagnose this.  In particular what is `FileNavPrompt` and related members? Is that a custom clsas object or separate module with module-level variables (e.g., `.financialFilePath`, `.mainBook`, etc.)?  If it is working for the other 3, I would take one of those and try to loop it...

Comment: I didn't use a loop because I wanted to keep the file operations completely separate from one another for the sake of being able to turn on/off certain imports later.  I thought I said what the global variables were but I must have left them out by accident.  `FileNavPrompt` is another module that has global variables attached to it.  It's where this sub gets called from.  `financialFilePath` is a string that contains the location of the file to open.  `mainBook` is a simplified reference to `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: Which line are you examining to see the empty range?

Comment: Second line of the "pull data" section.  I highlighted the expression after the equals and clicked Watch.

Comment: Are you sure that range *isn't* empty?  Some screenshots would be helpful: 1 screenshot of your Watch window expanded to show some of this, and 1 screenshot of that range on that worksheet.

Comment: Unfortunately due to the nature of the content I cannot provide screenshots, but I will test the range by calling a .Select statement on it and viewing the results.

Comment: Okay, tried the following statement on the range, gave me a runtime error "Select method of worksheets class failed."
`financialReportBook.Sheets(1).Range(copyRange).Select`
Added `financialReportBook.Sheets(1).Select` before it, same error.

This error triggers at the first select statement it comes across.

Comment: Make a "fake" workbook with dummy data. If you're not willing to put forth that much effort to get **free** assistance, you can hire someone to help you and have them sign an NDA.  It sounds to me like there is a problem with this file, either it is still protected or you have made some other errors or there is a problem in some other line of code that you have not shared here...

Comment: Is it possible that the sheet at index position 1 is a hidden sheet? In which case you couldn't possibly select it (or its range)? That might also explain the "emptiness" of the range values...

Comment: I'm sorry the privacy of this data has offended you.  I will take that into consideration next time someone graciously volunteers their assistance in my problem to any others who may have the same problem.  

Checking the sheet, Excel is not listing any hidden worksheets.  The "unhide" option is greyed out, and when I hide a sheet and unhide it again, that sheet I hid is the only one listed.  

I have a strong feeling this has something to do with the protection aspect of the workbook, though I can't understand why or how.

Comment: It's not the privacy of the data, the problem is that when you are not able provide information required for others to effectively assist you in troubleshooting, it's not reasonable to expect much assistance. After all, we can't read your mind or see your screen or step through your code, so you're basically just asking us to guess at the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem ended up being that the source workbook had it's sheet at index 1 attributed as xlVeryHidden.  This caused confusion when I would address the first visible sheet as index 1 instead of index 2 as it actually was.

Comment: Good lesson to use sheet names. Users can rearrange sheets too and you'll be up a creek when sheet index 5 turns into sheet index 3.

Comment: Good advice but unfortunately in my situation that was not an option (unless I used a regex of some kind) because the sheet name I was referring to has a date on it based on when the data was pulled.  I had to make sure that this wouldn't break a month from now when August's reports come in.

Comment: Maybe another very hidden sheet to keep track of the sheet names by name? Seems like even with a tricky naming convention users can still rearrange things

Comment: In my case it would be the person supplying the data that would make the change (user can't edit it because it's protected), in which case there are many other "assumptions" I've made that would be on the same risk level as the source moving the sheet around.